# Keep same video to continue play/loop between two "Inspiro slider" slides

Tags: html, slider

As the title says.

This code works as expected, but I wish to NOT reload (and start from beginning) the same video-background.

So that the video play/loop continuously between two slides, where the slide-content for each is just text. I've tried placing the video-background in parent divs, i.e. outside the two slider divs, but then it doesn't show up.

Please advise.

```
<!-- Inspiro Slider -->
    <div id="slider" class="inspiro-slider slider-fullscreen dots-creative" data-fade="true">
        <!-- Slide 1 -->
        <div class="slide" data-bg-video="video/homepage.mp4">
            <div class="bg-overlay"></div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="slide-captions text-start text-light">
                    <!-- Captions -->
                    <h2>HEADING FOR SLIDE ONE</h2>
                    <p class="text-small">
                    Paragraph text for slide 1
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end: Slide 1 -->
        
        <!-- Slide 2 -->
        <div class="slide" data-bg-video="video/homepage.mp4">
            <div class="bg-overlay"></div>
            <div class="container">
                 <div class="slide-captions text-start text-light">
                    <!-- Captions -->
                    <h2>HEADING FOR SLIDE TWO</h2>
                    <p class="text-small">
                    Paragraph text for slide 2
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end: Slide 2 -->
    </div>
    <!--end: Inspiro Slider -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Placing the bg video on the parent div, behind the slides should work.

```
<div id="slider" class="video-bg">
   <div> slide 1 </div>
   <div> slide 2 </div>
</div>
```

*but its hard to say without css or js*

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).